# How can i make bootstrap switch readonly?

Tags: angularjs, twitter-bootstrap-3

I want to make bootstrap switch by default on and read-only in angularJS.
This is my code:

```
<input type="checkbox" 
       ng-model="data.sla_enabled" 
       ng-readonly="true" 
       bs-switch 
       switch-size="mini" 
       ng-change="" 
       ng-checked="data.sla_enabled">
```

I use `ng-readonly` but It will not work.

Answer (score 1):

You need to keep checkbox **disabled** and **checked**. As shown below:

```html
<input type="checkbox" 
       ng-model="data.sla_enabled" 
       ng-readonly="true" 
       bs-switch 
       switch-size="mini" 
       ng-change="" 
       checked="checked"
       disabled="disabled">
```

Comment: Thanks it worked

`ng-change="" 
 checked="checked"
 disabled="disabled"`

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to use `ng-disabled` directive for checkboxes and not `ng-readonly`.

Here is an example:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.9/angular.min.js"></script>
<body>
   <div ng-app="">
     <label>Check me to make checkbox readonly: <input type="checkbox" ng-model="checked"></label><br/>
     <input type="checkbox" ng-disabled="checked" />
   </div>
</body>
</html>
```

More info you can find [here](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngDisabled):

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned by Rajmond use ng-disabled, just added a checked property to keep it ON by default.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.9/angular.min.js"></script>
<body>
   <div ng-app="">
     <input type="checkbox" checked ng-disabled="true"/>
   </div>
</body>
</html>
```